# json string shown in console, but the php variable print null

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following peace of javascript:

```
$('.showEditForm').click(function () {
    var webpagefileID = this.id;
    if($('#editForm').css('display', 'none')) {
        $('#editForm').css('display','block');
        $('#allFilesTable').css('display','none');
    }    
    $.post
    ('http://localhost/myproject/Controllername/display_edit_record_form', { webpagefileID: webpagefileID }, function(result) {

    });       
});
```

Using the post, I am calling method display_edit_record_form in my Codeigniter Controller

Here is the code of the method named `display_edit_record_form` in my CodeIgniter Controller:

```
public function display_edit_record_form($webpagefileID) {
    $webpagefileID = $this->input->post('webpagefileID');
    $data['webpagefile'] = $this->Webpage_file_model->get($webpagefileID);
    //$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data['webpagefile']));
    echo json_encode(array("message" => $data['webpagefile'] ));
}
```

In the php view, I am trying to display the data with following code:

```
var_dump($message);
echo "<br />";
$myarr1 = json_decode($message);
print_r($myarr1);
echo "<br />";
$myarr2 = json_decode($data['webpagefile']);
print_r($myarr2);
echo "<br />";
$myarr3 = json_decode($webpagefile);
print_r($myarr3);
```

And I get one NULL and 2 empty arrays
In the console however I can see this:

Now, in the console, when the edit form is opened, I can see the json string

```
{"message":
    {"webpagefileID":"10",
    "webpageID":"38",
    "webpagefileName":"New file",
    "webpagefileShowInRelatedFiles" :"1",
     .......continues.....
```

I need help to display this string in my php code in the view, so I can populate my form fields there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the output you are getting from `display_edit_record_form()` method is received in ajax. So your `$message` variable is showing blank.
What you need to do is after receiving the data from the `post` request, update your view using jquery.

```
$.post
    ('http://localhost/myproject/Controllername/display_edit_record_form', { webpagefileID: webpagefileID }, function(result) {
        result = $.parseJSON(result);
        // considering you have a text field with id myID
        $('#myID').val(result.message.webpagefileID);
        // similarly you can add any of your returned values
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the result in an php array in the view?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you want to have that result as php array in the view, you have to call the method in your controller and pass the value to the view. But in that case that won't be asynchronous right?

Comment: Yes, it is not what I want.

Comment: Then you have do it as mentioned in my answer

Comment: You are right, there is no other way. Do you know how can I add the result value as value of text field? String looks like this:{"result":{"webpagefileID":"12",...how to add the value 12 as value of the text field with id "myID"?

Comment: I can alert the result, but I can't add the value to the text field?!?

Comment: I had same id on the field as the name of the id, that causes the confusion. As soon as I changed the div, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when `json_decode()` result is `null` it means that the parsing was unsuccessful (usually is because of the string enconding).
You should be able to see the errorCode printing the output of [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)